# Membership.UpdateUser(user) does not update password and other options in the same time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Mates, I am having some logic problem here.

If I set the IsApproved true/false with any other setting, it has it´s value updated in the db.

Altough, When I set a new password all other settings that I am changing togheter with is´nt updated in the server.

Could you help me:

*CONTROLLER*

```
public ActionResult EditUser(EditModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            try
            {
                MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);

                user.IsApproved = bool.Parse(Request.Form.GetValues("IsApproved")[0]);

                if (model.PasswordAccount != null)
                    user.ChangePassword(model.PasswordAccount, model.NewPassword);


                if (model.PasswordQuestion != null)
                    user.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(model.CurrentPass, model.PasswordQuestion, model.PasswordAnwser);   


                if (model.Email != null)
                {
                    bool emailExist = CheckEmail(model.Email);
                    if (emailExist == false)
                    {
                        user.Email = model.Email;
                    }
                }

                Membership.UpdateUser(user);

                return Content("Usuário Atualizado com Sucesso!");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Content("Usuário não atualizado - Erro: " + e);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return Content("Model Inválido");
        }

    }
```

I don´t get erros and checking with debug I don´t get anu error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is not the best way but it is working and until I find a better solutions this is working:

```
try
            {
                MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);

                user.IsApproved = bool.Parse(Request.Form.GetValues("IsApproved")[0]);

                if (model.Email != null)
                {
                    bool emailExist = CheckEmail(model.Email);
                    if (emailExist == false)
                    {
                        user.Email = model.Email;
                    }
                }

                Membership.UpdateUser(user);

                user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);

                if (model.PasswordAccount != null)
                    user.ChangePassword(model.PasswordAccount, model.NewPassword);


                if (model.PasswordQuestion != null)
                    user.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(model.CurrentPass, model.PasswordQuestion, model.PasswordAnwser);

                Membership.UpdateUser(user);

                return Content("Usuário Atualizado com Sucesso!");

            }
```